# VM keeps losing IP configuration, network adapter has to be reset several times a day

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtual-machine, parallels

I am running a W10 VM on Parallels on a Mac host. The VM has a virtual ethernet adapter using "shared network" set to automatically assign IP4 address, DNS, etc. The Mac host is connected via ethernet to the router. It uses DHCP (I think) but is only restarted once or twice a week.

The problem is that frequently, the VM loses network/internet access. Running troubleshooter quickly fixes it:
[image]

This *only* seems to happen when the VM is idle i.e. not using the internet connection. If I have a VPN connection it will typically work for hours or days. If I turn that off and go away for a few minutes, it is typically broken when I return, like the connection is 'sleeping'.

This is the ethernet adapter settings (Ethernet 3 above is a VPN virtual adapter, Ethernet is the shared VM network from my Mac).

[image]

What settings can I change either in my Windows VM or in Parallels to stop this happening? I had been suggested to manually assign a fixed IP but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: ps: Is this a SU or SF Q? I presumed the former as I'm not a sysadmin :)

Comment: In Windows, check in the network adapter properties in Power management if the "Disable this device to save power" option wouldn't be checked, and if so, uncheck it. You may have to do the same in Device Manager, and also in Power options, under your power plan, then Advanced options, in the WiFi section (I know, it sounds stupid, but virtual network adapters don't work exactly the same way as physical ones).

Comment: If @Didier's suggestion doesn't work, you may want to assign it a static IP on the router.

Comment: @JW0914 how would I assign a VM a static IP on the router? Or perhaps you mean the host (Mac)... this typically runs 24/7 so I don't think its IP is changing very frequently, certainly far less so than the problems occur

Comment: @Mr.Boy Provided the VM's interface is communicating with the router and not a hypervisor proxy on the host _(such as with Hyper-V's default adapter in Windows 10)_, the same way you would assign any other device a static IP, except with a VM, it needs to also be assigned a static MAC first either in the hypervisor settings or within the VM itself.

Comment: @JW0914 no idea how Parallels handles this. All I know is it's set to share network connection.